# Magento 2 How to override banktransfer.html file in custom module

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add custom text box by custom module throw overriding this file

`"vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/banktransfer.html"`

to my custom module. Please share your idea or suggestions to make this code working.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add requiredjs-config.js :

```
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
           'module-offline-payments/template/payment/banktransfer.html':
            'namespace/ModuleName/template/payment/banktransfer.html'
      }
  }
};
```

After override this html template remove `pub/static` and apply 
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Thanks for help what i require is to store data when any user clicks on place order button. Can you share code for the same?